# Как узнать скорость и вектор движения указателя мыши?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я начинаю изучать C# и хочу попрактиковаться с векторами. Я сделал WPF приложение, в котором на ПКМ создаются круги, а если нажать и удерживать ЛКМ, то их можно двигать и при отпускании ЛКМ они должны продолжать движение со скоростью указателя мыши. У меня не получается сделать, чтоб они продолжали движение с нужной скоростью, она не меняется. как можно узнать скорость указателя?
P.S. я пробовал узнать вектор через сохранение предыдущей координаты и вычитанием ее из прошлой.

```
// при отпускании мыши
Vector mousemove = new Vector(Mouse.GetPosition(main).X - lastpos.X, Mouse.GetPosition(main).Y - lastpos.Y);
elipse[i].direction = mousemove / mousemove.Length; // elipse - класс, содержащий круг (Elipse) и вектор его движения (direction)

//в таймере
lastpos = new Point(Mouse.GetPosition(main).X, Mouse.GetPosition(main).Y);
```

Comment: чтобы узнать вектор, надо из кончных координат мыши вычесть начальные. Чтобы узнать скорость, надо расстояние разделить на время.

Comment: у меня вроде так и есть, но не работает

Comment: ну так приведите код или пример, который можно скопировать и запустить. Просто фраза "это не работает" сама по себе ничего не значит.